# How to make bootstrap datepicker appear onclick on input field and icon at the same time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using `datepicker` of bootstrap and I'm trying to make the pop up appear  whenever I click on the icon or in the input field

I'm using `bootstrap3` :[datepicker docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

this is my `script` :

```
 $(function () {
        $('#start-date').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'MM-YYYY'
        });
```

and `html`:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label for="start-date">Start Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ start_date }}"
                                   id="start-date">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution :

this worked for me

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <label for="start-date">Start Date</label>
   <div class="input-group date">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ start_date }}"
                               id="start-date">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="start-date"><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can trigger the click and then show the datepicker like this, if i understood well :

```
$('#start-date').click(function () {
    $('#myField').datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying fast.. I tried this one but when I click on input and then on the calendar button two datepickers are shown overwhelmed

Comment: Then, do something like this : a=$('#start-date','#start-date-datepicker');
a.click(function () {
    $('#myField').datepicker("show");
});

And try to don't use the same ID for the datepicker ?

Comment: Thanks a lot..it works but one question ..how can I set parameters of datepicker so that I display only years `viewMode: 'years',` ... I mean How can I add this when I have `show` attribute ?

Comment: According to jquery documentation : [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show)
 you can't 

But you could do something like :  `$("#start-date").focus(function () {
                    $(".ui-datepicker-days").hide();
                });`

.ui-datepicker is in the CSS , and it's here that you should hide everything :)

Anyway you can use showOn: $('#start-date'),


And, mark question as resolved, if you're OK

Answer (score 0):

Simples - use a **class**! (This may **NOT** work for **you**! Please see * below.)

HTML =

```
<div class="input-group date fooClass" id="startTime">
  <!-- style="position: relative"-->
  <input class="form-control fooClass" id="startTime1" type="text" name="startTime">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

JS =

```
<script>
  $('.fooClass').datetimepicker({
      format: 'LT',
      keepOpen: true
  });
</script>
```

Worked for me but I have a slightly weird download. I could not find the "current" download at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ so I downloaded the CDN sources they were using.

* I am using latest Bootstrap **3** (not 4) and jQuery v3.4.1 . There are all sorts of versions of `bootstrap-datetimepicker` out there and different versions require different jQuerys. So this may not work for you.

PS Just looked and they are using JQ v2.1.1 so guess I got lucky that anything works!